# How should I troubleshoot a dishwasher that stops in the last minute of the cycle?

Tags: electrical, dishwasher

I have an LG model # LDS5040ST dishwasher.  I found it displaying an nE error code the other day.  The code description on the LG site says it is thrown due to the vario motor locking.  Today I tore it down to look at the motor.  I found some trash and a chewed up toothpick in the sump by the motor impeller.  I cleaned it all up,  put it back together (because if  I have to order a new motor it won't get here until Mar. 5), and tried to run it.  I watched it run for the whole cycle.  It got to 001 left then it beeped and threw the nE error again.  But I heard the motor running.  What should my next steps in troubleshooting be?  Could it be a control panel issue?

Comment: Try taking the pump apart again and cleaning, check the drain hose and impeller intake.

Answer (score 1):

What you might have is a loose wire in the front panel ; this appears to be a common problem with Vario Motor errors on the LG Washers.

Verify that the motor turns and does not have any rough spots or stiff spots, check your sump and impeller areas again to be sure - but you are likely looking at a loose wire in the front panel.
Apparently the cables get stuck on something in the door panel and lose their flexibility and get pulled loose or apart - or wiggle to an internal breakage (this happens when the door is opened and closed).

The other possibility could also be the main board.